# Increasing the traits requirement for a type in Rust

Tags: rust, traits

Suppose I have the following

```
pub struct A { type M : Eq + PartialOrd; }
```

How can I create something like

```
struct B { type N : Eq + PartialOrd + std::hash::Hash; }
```

Without necessarily referencing Eq + PartialOrd but instead reference directly M and write something like

```
type N = A::M + std::hash::Hash;
```

Comment: Sadly, I don't think you can. Your best bet might be making a new trait with all the requirements as supertraits.

Answer (score 3):

It is still **unstable**, but the way of doing this would be [`trait_alias`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/trait-alias.html):

```rust
#![feature(trait_alias)]

trait At = Eq + PartialOrd;
trait Bt = At + std::hash::Hash;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3ca501fc9994e3799a4dfe1f0167244f)